# Jquery DataTable fixed coulmn appears with scrollbar and Overlapping

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have jquery datatable with fixed column and it appears with scroll bar and Overlapping.

Plugins:

```
<link href="../../Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../Content/dataTables.jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../Scripts/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/tableExport.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.base64.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#srch th').each(function () {
            var title = $('#srch th').eq($(this).index()).text();
            if (title == "Preffered") {
                alert("in");
                $(this).html('<input type="checkbox" />');
            }
            else if (title != "") {
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
            }
            else {
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" style="visibility:hidden" />');
            }
        });

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#ERHCtbl').DataTable(
        {           
            sScrollY: 150,            
            scrollX: true,            
            scrollCollapse: true,            
            fixedColumns: {
                leftColumns: 1
            }
        });
        table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
            $('input', 'th:nth-child(' + (colIdx + 1) + ')').on('keyup change', function () {
                table
                    .column(colIdx)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
        });
    });
```

Html:

```
<table id="ERHCtbl">
            <thead>
                 <tr style="background-color: #4a70ae; color: white" id="srch">
                    <th> C1 </th>
                    <th> C2 </th>
                    <th> C3 </th>
                    <th> C4 </th>
                    <th> C5 </th>
                    <th> C6 </th>
                    <th> C7 </th>
                    <th> C8 </th>
                    <th> C9 </th>
                    <th> C10 </th>
                    <th> C11 </th>
                    <th> C12 </th>
                    <th> C13 </th>
                    <th> C14 </th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #4a70ae; color: white">
                    <th> C1 </th>
                    <th> C2 </th>
                    <th> C3 </th>
                    <th> C4 </th>
                    <th> C5 </th>
                    <th> C6 </th>
                    <th> C7 </th>
                    <th> C8 </th>
                    <th> C9 </th>
                    <th> C10 </th>
                    <th> C11 </th>
                    <th> C12 </th>
                    <th> C13 </th>
                    <th> C14 </th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
    </thead>
```

Output:
[image]

In the above picture First column is fixed but it appears with scroll and Overlapping

Comment: Since you are using a plugin. your actual html will be converted to some other elements say for example ul and li. So view the source of the document and style those accordingly. Or the plugin may have its css find the column and set its style.

Comment: @Abel D, Yes u r correct, This Jquery Data table is a partial view and in Main page i am using jquery-ui.js for accoridon so the style is modified. Is there any other alternative solution for this

Comment: I am not used much with jquery-ui. sorry.